# Is there a way to get cross domain of web page inside of Iframe in webbrowser control?

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control, cross-domain

I've been searching around the way to at least know what domain the iframe (with cross-domain) in the web page has, using .NET WebBrowser control.

I'm using .NET 2.0 Visual Studio 2005 C#

For instance in the webbrowser control, it has web page with iframe with different domain.

I want to get the value "www.google.com"

**http://localhost/index.html**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="http://www.google.com/foobar"></iframe>  
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to get domain and getting `UnauthorizedAccessException` due to Cross Domain Scripting according to MSDN.

```
  HtmlWindowCollection frames = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames;
  if (frames.Count > 0)
  {
    for (int i = 0, j = frames.Count; i < j; i++)
    {                        
      //if the iframe in the page has different domain
      if (frames[i].Document.Domain != this.webBrowser1.Document.Domain)
      {
         MessageBox.Show("iframe has different domain");
      }
    }
  }
```

But looks like I can't even get access to the domain.

I've tried Url too `frames[i].Url` and still same exception.

Does this mean I can't really get any information from the Iframe other than it is an iframe? Is there a way to detect if an iframe has different domain without throwing exception?

Comment: hmm looks like not, accessing any method, properties below HtmlDocument is throwing UnauthorizedAccessException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a security feature of browsers to stop people being scammed. Otherwise you could embed their favourite bank website in an iFrame and extract data from it.